# How to fix USB not showing up?

Tags: windows-10, usb, bootable-media

I was trying to make bootable USB for windows 7 for my friend with rufus tool.It worked fine,but when i restarted my Windows 10 I have stopped seeing my USB.I see it in **DISK MANAGMENT** though:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your USB stick doesn't have a disk letter. In the disk management click right mouse button on **Disk 1** and select item Change disk letter. In the pop up window select your usb stick and click on Change. In the next windows select the letter for usb stick.

Comment: It worked like a magic!Thank you.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct and put +1. I need reputation.

Comment: I tried but I just made account so StackExchange wont let me vote, unfortunately.

Comment: However when i reach reputation 15 i will upvote you,i wont forget,i am on 11 right now.